# How to erase an array value into en session with the set method?

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have a array into a session variable:

```
$data = array('test1' => 'val1', 'test2' => 'val2');
$Session->set('data', $data);
```

How can I erase the `$data['test2']` from the session? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset($data['test2']);
$Session->set('data', $data);
```

But why not setting two different attributes ?

```
$Session->set('test1', $data['test1']);
$Session->set('test2', $data['test2']);
```

In this case you will be able to use the `remove()` function.
Or alternatively you can extend the `Session` and create a function that will do the job.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session as BaseSession,

class Session extends BaseSession
{
    function removeFromData($key) 
    {
        $data = $this->get('data');
        unset($data[$key]);
        $this->set('data', $data)
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see he wants to delete one value of the session array. not the whole thing

Comment: Oh your are right thanks, I read the question too fast, I have modified my answer.